# Make cell editable with JButton

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I'm stuck for two days on a piece of code, the cells of my table are non-editable default and I want to editable when I click on the edit button, but I can not run this code.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
table = new JTable(model) {
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
sorter = new TableRowSorter < TableModel > (model);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(560, 200));
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane((table));
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
add(ScrollPane);
scrollPane.setBounds(10, 180, 560, 200);
table.setRowHeight(28);
table.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
table.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
modifier.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ((JButton) e.getSource() == change) {
            boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put enabled cell (row, col) to a set and make your table use that set to check if cell is enabled.

```
package javaapplication33;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.Box;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class JavaApplication33
{    

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());                
                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

                final Set<Point> erc = new HashSet<>(); //this set contains (row,cell) pairs of editable cells

                //put some data to the table
                final JTable table = new JTable(new String[][] 
                    {{"a", "aa"},
                    {"b", "bb"},
                    {"c", "cc"}},
                        new String[]{"col1", "col2"}) //name columns
                {                    
                    Collection<Point> editableRowsCells = erc;
                    Collection<Point> getEditableRowsCells()
                    {
                        return editableRowsCells;
                    }                    
                    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
                    {
                        return getEditableRowsCells()
                                .contains(new Point(row, column));
                    }
                };

                table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);                
                JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table); 

                p.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

                table.setRowHeight(28);
                table.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                table.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

                final JTextField xf = new JTextField();
                final JTextField yf = new JTextField();
                Action enableAction = new AbstractAction("Enable")
                {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        int row = Integer.valueOf(xf.getText());
                        int col = Integer.valueOf(yf.getText());
                        erc.add(new Point(row,col));
                        ((AbstractTableModel) table.getModel())
                                .fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
                    }
                };
                JButton enableButton = new JButton();
                enableButton.setAction(enableAction);
                Box b = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
                b.add(new JLabel("Row"));
                b.add(xf);
                b.add(new JLabel("Col"));                
                b.add(yf);
                b.add(enableButton);

                p.add(b, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                f.add(p);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }

}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Update: **to make all cells editable**

```
package javaapplication33;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class JavaApplication33
{

    public static class Toggle
    {
        Boolean val;

        public Toggle(Boolean val)
        {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public void setVal(Boolean val)
        {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public Boolean getVal()
        {
            return val;
        }

        public void toggle()
        {
            setVal(!getVal());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

                final Toggle editable = new Toggle(false);

                final JTable table = new JTable(
                        new String[][]{
                            {"a", "aa"},
                            {"b", "bb"},
                            {"c", "cc"}},
                        new String[] {"col1", "col2"}) //name columns
                        {                           
                            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
                            {
                                return editable.getVal(); //request current value
                            }
                        };

                table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

                p.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                table.setRowHeight(28);
                table.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                table.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

                Action enableAction = new AbstractAction("Toggle editable")
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        editable.toggle(); //toggle current value
                        ((AbstractTableModel) table.getModel()).fireTableStructureChanged();
                    }
                };
                JButton enableButton = new JButton();
                enableButton.setAction(enableAction);

                p.add(enableButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                f.add(p);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But why I will be forced to go through JTextField , just a button that puts all non- editable cells in editable, Because my amendment will be done on a database

Comment: Then it is even easier to make all cells editable. Is that what you want: make **all cells editable**?

Answer (score 0):

Here my code :

```
table = new JTable(model){
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {

                    return false;
                } 

            };
                modifier.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    if ((JButton)e.getSource()== modifier)
                    {
                            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {

                                return true;

                            }
                        }   
                }    

            });
```